# Cannot find binary file in storage

Tags: c#, uwp, storagefile

I am trying to access and read a binary file in my project but I keep getting the following error:

> The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80070002)

I first tried accessing it like this:

```
StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("myBinaryFile");
                Stream stream = (await file.OpenReadAsync()).AsStreamForRead();
                BinaryReader brFile = new BinaryReader(stream);
```

and then I tried using this instead to access it:

```
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri(@"ms-appx:///myBinaryFile"));
```

But both of them returned the same error.
Any ideas?

Comment: did you try adding the extension?

Comment: What extension? The file has no extension.

Comment: the file extension

Comment: Do I need to add an extension on my file? and what should I add? The file as a file has none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you get file with wrong path. You can access files in the l**ocal app data** store using the "ms-appdata:///local/" protocol. For example:

```
ms-appdata:///local/myBinaryFile
```

You could also use [ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder#Windows_Storage_ApplicationData_LocalFolder) API the get file, please make sure the file has stored in the local folder. And the folder path looks like 
`C:\Users\Account\AppData\Local\Packages\3e8cf79a-4746-457c-8f51-73809c7876fa_75cr2b68xxxx\LocalState`

Use the `ms-appx`  URI scheme to refer to a file that comes from your **app's package**. and you could also use [`InstalledLocation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.package.installedlocation#Windows_ApplicationModel_Package_InstalledLocation) API.

For more detail, you could refer [URI schemes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/uri-schemes)